# Homology groups of the complex projective plane of dimension 2 - an affine line and a point not in the line

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is a question from a problem sheet we had in class and the solution says the following :
We first note  that the complex projective plane of dimension 2 minus an affine line is isomorphic to $C^2$ and therefore the complex projective plane minus an affine line and a point not in the line will be isomorphiC to $C^2$-{0} which is isomorphic to $S^3$. But I think that this is wrong. From what I know $\mathbb{P}^2 \cong C^2 \cup \mathbb{P}$ therefore the complex projective plane of dimension 2 minus an affine line and a point not in the line should just be isomorphic to $C^2$. What am I saying wrong here
Thanks in advance

Comment: But the exersise says that I have to subdract an affine line and a point not in the line. $P^1 \cong $(affine line and a point not in the line) isn't that right. So I expected $P^1$ - affine line to give you a point therefore when i subdract $P^1$ - affine line and a point to give $\emptyset$

Comment: $\Bbb CP^1$ is not disjoint union of an affine line and a point, because the latter is disconnected but the former is connected.

Comment: so is $CP^1$ $\cong$ affine line?

Comment: No, it's not. $\Bbb CP^1$ is a projective line, homeomorphic to $S^1$. An affine line is just a copy of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TheGeometer: I'd guess the solutions should have read "(minus a) _projective_ line" rather than "affine line".

Comment: yeah thats what I think. I don't see why $C^2 \cup CP^1$  minus $C$ should be $C^2$

Comment: Whoops, yes, I was confusing affine line with projective line. $\Bbb CP^2 -\Bbb (\Bbb C \cup \{0\})$ is indeed homeomorphic to $\Bbb C$, while $\Bbb CP^2 - (\Bbb CP^1 \cup \{0\}) \cong \Bbb C^2 - \{0\}$